# Meteor : Fundamental Database Strategy Scenario

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, meteor

The Html Page Looks like this :

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>MP3</title>
</head>

<body>
{{> download}}
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            {{#each songs}} {{> okay}} {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<template name="download">
    <input type="text" id="songname">
    <button id="hitit">Submit</button>
</template>
<template name="okay">
 <form action="{{linksong}}">
    <li><input type="submit" value="Download {{kbps}} kbps" id = "{{kbps}}"></li></form>
</template>
```

Now, from the input button, I use this code to add it to minimongo collecction :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var inputterm = document.getElementById("songname");
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("hitit");

    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

      SearchTerm.insert({
        sub: inputterm.value

      });



    }, false);
});
```

Then I have to access the term I added to the database, query it, and add the result to a new database.

**Q1 : I don't know how to query the database to extract the same term.**

But, before that, a fundamental question arises :

Let's say there are ten users using the app at the same time from different locatons, and they hit submit at different times but before anyone has got a response.

THe query is added to the same database for all the users. SO, the one who fires the last query will get the correct result and the rest will be like : "What the hell?"

**All I'm trying to say, if this app is going to have thousand users, is it Viable to create seperate databases for all of them, and if yes, then how can it be implemented?
And Is there any other way like Sessions, publish and subscribe, and do they fit the above scenario ?**

Plus it is a download song sort of a website, so there is no point asking the user to login or whatever.

Comment: Is it viable to create databases for all of them? It is not only viable, it is what's already happening: Meteor spawns a minimongo instance on each client. Also, if all you do is query the server for a set of non-reactive data, you should use a [method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods).

Comment: What do you mean by non-reactive?

Comment: Plus, the point is, even if it is creating a minimongo at the client side, at the server side, the method for querying is querying the original database. So, that leads to inconsistent results.

Comment: You need to read way more on Meteor if you don't know what reactivity and non-reactivity are. Meteor has its own paradigms and patterns.

Comment: So are you trying to say that even if the data changes, the users will get the consistent results, because of the minimongo thing?

Comment: Before Q1, Meteor has events hash for each template to handle events.

Comment: is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to save the term and then ... query it? in other clients?

Comment: could you explain in terms in users flow, without including technical details

Comment: You are in US and there is another user in India. Now, both are using the app. They both enter the query and hit submit. This, chnages the view on both the clients, because of the way meteor handles events. How do I make evry session unique for every user?

Comment: I highly recommend reading the Discover Meteor book - https://book.discovermeteor.com/ - go through the whole thing and code along. Don't just go floundering inside of Meteor unaided since you really need to know how it's working underneath or else you'll tear your hair out.